# simple JSON parser/Generator for C++ (Windows VS 2010)

Tags: json, visual-c++, tcp, network-programming

Can someone suggest simple JSON parser for C++ Windows VS 2010, possible which can be used for commercial purpose without licensing issues.

The requirement is to

1. Fetch and package the data in JSON from C++ program,
2. It would be transferred over network (TCP socket) and would further be read from Android device.
3. The data is to be sent is light, not very heavy.

Thanks.

Comment: Below one are available parsers for C++, but which one is most recommeded?JSONKit.
jsonme--.
ThorsSerializer.
JsonBox.
jsoncpp.
zoolib.
JOST.
CAJUN.
libjson.
nosjob.
rapidjson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/) and its [property tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) library can create and parse [JSON](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.json_parser).

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the same, we were already planning to use boost for networking and thread synchronization considering it;s roubstness.